# I want to add an additional column to my df based on multiple condition on another column, all these condition are w.r.t string matching

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
    import pandas as pd
    name = 
    r"C:\Users\saarif2201\Desktop\Classification\Vidio_Indonesia\VidioDataset-Apr'22.xlsx"
    df = pd.read_excel(name)
    consist = ["Episode","Ep"]
    def cat_marking(x):
        if consist in (x):
          return "Series"
        else:
          return ""

    df['Content_Category'] = df['vod_episode_name'].apply(cat_marking)
```

This I have written to add a column name content_category and mark some of its rows as series based on the condition(that it contains Episode or Ep as a string) on vod_episode_name column.

Answer (score 0):

I can't access the .xlsx file you posted, but I think that the following code should work for you if you want to apply your function to the `vod_episode_name` column.

```
import pandas as pd
name = r"C:\Users\saarif2201\Desktop\Classification\Vidio_Indonesia\VidioDataset-Apr'22.xlsx"

df = pd.read_excel(name)


consist = ["Episode","Ep"]

def cat_marking(x):
    if any(ext in x for ext in consist):
        return "Series"
    else:
        return ""


    
df['Content_Category'] = df['vod_episode_name'].apply(lambda x: cat_marking(x))
```